# How to display data from Mysql to EJS template with WHERE clause? such as ID

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, ejs

how can i display the data from Node JS and Mysql db to EJS template with WHERE clause such as id, username or email.

i try this code from Node server.js with hard coded id no. 2 and i want to display this select from mysql to EJS template with where Clause id

```
router.get("/users", (req, res) => {

    db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 2', function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
  
        ///res.render() function
        res.render('users', {data: result});
      });
    // res.render("users")
})

I want this to be display in input type values like this


<input type="text" value="<%= data.id %>">
```

Comment: Are you using ejs view engine?

Comment: yes i am using view engine of EJS

Comment: Can you try to console log `result`

Comment: thank you i found a solution to it by using json then append it by vanilla js